npm build is failing due to lodash
Using
Node: 16.20.2
Angular: CLI 11.2.5
Typescript: 4.1.5
@types/lodash: 4.14.177
npm build started failing with below exception

Error: node modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1026:46 error TS1005: '?' expected.
1026 : K extends $(infer N extends number)? T[N]
Error: node modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1026:51 error T52536: Type 'N' cannot be used to index type 'T'.
1026 K extends $(infer N extends number)? T[N]
Error: node modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1031:46 error TS1005: '?' expected.
1031 K extends $(infer N extends number)?[N]
Error: node modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1031:51 error T52536: Type 'N' cannot be used to index type 'T
1031 : extends $(infer i extends number) [N]
Error: node modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:1041:46 error TS1005: ? expected.
1041 extends $infer i extends number)

Tried lodash 4.14.168 but getting same error

This version of lodash relies on a feature that was shipped with Typescript 4.7.
You'll need to downgrade the lodash typings, 4.14.190 is the latest that supports TS 4.1.
Btw, the error you are sharing definitely shows that 4.14.177 is not the version that is installed. check the package.json in node_modules/@types/lodash.
